# How can I mount NFS at the home folder under Win7?

Tags: windows-7, nfs

I found some tutorial where I can mount NFS as a drive, but I haven't found any tutorial regarding how can I mount NFS at the home folder under Win7?

Comment: Why don't you mount it as a drive and create a shortcut to it from the home folder?

Comment: Is it possible to do this automatically, when I'm creating a new user?

Comment: Don't use NFS-mounts on Windows clients unless someone's forcing you at gunpoint.